# Calculating the 95th Percentile value, but not necessarily from the dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, statistics

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the 95th percentile value off of a given dataset. I can use the T-SQL below to get the 95th percentile value **from** the data-set, but the code below always gives me the value **from** the data-set.

```
SELECT MIN(Value) 
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 95 PERCENT WITH TIES Value
    FROM [Sample].[dbo].[numbers]
    ORDER BY Value DESC
) AS Temp
```

For example, for the data-set **23, 5, 11, 22, 25, 14**, the 95th percentile value is 24.5 per Excel, but SQL Server is not going to return this value as it is not in the data-set.

Can anyone please advise if they have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Comment: There are more than one type of percentiles out there so you have to know which one you want.  It might not be possible with sql alone.  When I had to do something like this, I got the records from sql and calculated the percentiles with ColdFusion.

Comment: @sgeddes . . . It is making radical assumptions about the distribution.  I think the correct answer is 25, which is what SQL should be returning.  The probable reason for the interpolation in Excel is to handle medians when there are an even number of rows.  Even so, all numbers between the two middle values are equally valid, so there is an argument for any value in between and even either end point.

Comment: This may be of help: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/08/23/t-sql-thoughts-about-the-95th-percentile.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want an "interpolated" median.  Yucch.  But, you can do this with SQL.  Just be explicit in the calculation:

```
select (max(case when rownum <= 0.95 * total then value end) +
        min(case when rownum >= 0.95 * total then value end)
       ) / 2.0 as Interpolated_95th
from (SELECT n.*, row_number() over (order by value) as rownum,
             count(*) over () as total
      FROM [Sample].[dbo].[numbers] n
     ) t
```

Note that this works in the case where there are exactly a multiple of 20 rows (so the 95th percentile would be at 19x position), because of the equality -- `min()` and `max()` would be the same.  If also works in other cases, always returning the point half-way in-between the two values.

Note:  I don't really think this is any more valid than the value that SQL returns.  By the definition of median and percentile, any value between the two is equally valid, and there is a good argument for using either extreme.  That said, I can greatly appreciate that in the real world, you might have to do this.

Comment: thank you for your help. can you please confirm if the above logic is not going to work if the number of rows is NOT a multiple of 20? Thanks again/

Comment: @sam1980 . . . The above code works to interpolate the values (ala Excel) regardless of the number of values.